# Upgrading a clean 1.9.1.1 installation to 1.9.2, how?

Tags: ce-1.9.2.0

Can somebody suggest the easiest way to upgrade from 1.9.1.1 installation to 1.9.2 ? Can it be done in-place without an intermediary server ?

ConnectManager may be one way, but is failing for me, so I am wondering what is another way to apply the upgrade in the  1.9.2 zip file ?

I have the question posted here, but there doesn't seem to be valid replies so far ... http://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/Was-unable-to-upgrade-from-1-9-1-1-to-1-9-2-0-using/m-p/10186#M572

Answer (score 4):

Disable all store caches and download the 1.9.2.0 source and replace your existing codebase with it.

Comment: `tar -xzf magento-1.9.2.0.tar.gz` from the command line in doc root is the surest method if you have Magento installed in the `magento/` directory. SFTP is dead slow and suffers timeouts as it has to iterate through the directory structure. Umm, Magento Connect, well the less said about it, the better... other than Friends don't let Friends do drugs. It can be a really bad trip. Discovery of [git repositories](https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/our-magento-git-guide-and-work-flow/) in future wouldn't be a bad thing. Had to give you a plug...

Comment: Ok thanks for helping .. you suggest just overwriting the files of this non-customized installation ? But what about database updates.. 1.9.2 ( and upcoming upgrades ) may include database updates besides file system changes ... so there has to be an additional step in that regard ....

Comment: Magento has set-up scripts for DB changes, so that would be automatic.

Answer (score 0):

BEFORE UPDATE:

- DEACTIVATE COMPILER
- SAVE INDEX.PHP & .HTACCESS
- MAKE DATABASE BACKUP

When using the Magento Connect:
- SET THE RIGHTS: (750/644 better: 755/644)

When using the FTP Upload (Works better for me):
- Overwrite your Magento

Think about:
- PLUGINS & BUY THEMES SUPPORT?

AFTER UPDATE
- If mssing Graphics (internal server error): HTACCESS in /media delete/edit)
- INDEX.PHP & .HTACCESS DIFF // MULTISTORE CODE?
- TMP FOLDER THERE?
Firstly, copy /lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php to /app/code/local/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php.

Then on line 91 or near this line, you will find:
'cache_dir' => null,
Change to:
'cache_dir' => "var/tmp/",

- CACHE EMPTY?
- SESSION KILLED?
- CRONJOB OK?
- CORE FUNCTIONS WORKING? Make an Order

Answer (score -1):

I made it work

In ConnectManger I only needed to update the Mage All module.